# TensorFlow Serving on Docker with my own retrained inception model

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I followed the links https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/ and https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflow-for-poets/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0 , and I ran my server without any problems.

Now I want to server my own retrained model. I have my retrained graph and I do some inference and everything is OK. But when I export my Graph to serving and I run the model_server, the responses are wrong (my labels are missing and the scores are strange).

I'm exporting using the follow code:

```
def export(session, image_lists):
 synsets = []
 with open('D:\\imagenet_lsvrc_2015_synsets.txt') as f:
  synsets = f.read().splitlines()
 ## Create synset->metadata mapping
 texts = {}
 with open('D:\\imagenet_metadata.txt') as f:
   for line in f.read().splitlines():
     parts = line.split('\t')
     assert len(parts) == 2
     texts[parts[0]] = parts[1]

 with session.graph.as_default():
   # Build inference model.
   # Please refer to Tensorflow inception model for details.

   # Input transformation.
   serialized_tf_example = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='tf_example')
   feature_configs = {
    'image/encoded': tf.FixedLenFeature(
        shape=[], dtype=tf.string),
   }
   tf_example = tf.parse_example(serialized_tf_example, feature_configs)
   jpegs = tf_example['image/encoded']
   images = tf.map_fn(preprocess_image, jpegs, dtype=tf.float32)

  # Run inference.
   logits, _ = inception_model.inference(images, 2 + 1)

   # Transform output to topK result.
   values, indices = tf.nn.top_k(logits, 3)

   print(str(values))

   # Create a constant string Tensor where the i'th element is
   # the human readable class description for the i'th index.
   # Note that the 0th index is an unused background class
   # (see inception model definition code).

   class_descriptions = ['unused background']
   for s in synsets:
     class_descriptions.append(texts[s])


   #class_descriptions = ['unused background']
   #class_descriptions = ['unused background', 'noeyeglasses', 'eyeglasses']
   #for label_index, label_name in enumerate(image_lists.keys()):
   #print(str(label_index))
   #class_descriptions.append(label_name)


   #print(class_descriptions)
   class_tensor = tf.constant(class_descriptions)

   print("criou o class_tensor: ", class_tensor)

   classes = tf.contrib.lookup.index_to_string(
    tf.to_int64(indices), mapping=class_tensor)

   print("criou classes")

   # Restore variables from training checkpoint.
   variable_averages = tf.train.ExponentialMovingAverage(
    inception_model.MOVING_AVERAGE_DECAY)
   variables_to_restore = variable_averages.variables_to_restore()
   saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
   #with tf.Session() as sess:
   with session as sess:
    # Restore variables from training checkpoints.
    ckpt = tf.train.get_checkpoint_state(FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    #if ckpt and ckpt.model_checkpoint_path:
    #  saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
    #  # Assuming model_checkpoint_path looks something like:
    #  #   /my-favorite-path/imagenet_train/model.ckpt-0,
    #  # extract global_step from it.
    #  global_step = ckpt.model_checkpoint_path.split('/')[-1].split('-')[-1]
    #  print ('Successfully loaded model from %s at step=%s.' % (
    #      ckpt.model_checkpoint_path, global_step))
    #else:
    #  print ('No checkpoint file found at %s' % FLAGS.checkpoint_dir)
    #  return

    # Export inference model.
    output_path = os.path.join(
      compat.as_bytes(FLAGS.output_dir),
      compat.as_bytes(str(FLAGS.model_version)))
    print ('Exporting trained model to', output_path)
    builder = saved_model_builder.SavedModelBuilder(output_path)

    # Build the signature_def_map.
    print ('classify_inputs_tensor_info')
    classify_inputs_tensor_info = utils.build_tensor_info(
      serialized_tf_example)
    classes_output_tensor_info = utils.build_tensor_info(classes)
    scores_output_tensor_info = utils.build_tensor_info(values)

    print ('classification_signature')
    classification_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={
          signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classify_inputs_tensor_info
      },
      outputs={
          signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
              classes_output_tensor_info,
          signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_SCORES:
              scores_output_tensor_info
      },
      method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)

    predict_inputs_tensor_info = utils.build_tensor_info(jpegs)

    print ('prediction_signature')
    prediction_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
      inputs={'images': predict_inputs_tensor_info},
      outputs={
          'classes': classes_output_tensor_info,
          'scores': scores_output_tensor_info
      },
      method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)


    print (prediction_signature)
    print ('legacy_init_op')
    legacy_init_op = tf.group(
      tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')

    print ('initialize_all_variables')
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()


    sess.run(init)      
    sess.run(legacy_init_op)

    print ('builder')
    builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
      sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
      signature_def_map={
          'predict_images':
              prediction_signature,
          signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
              classification_signature,
      },
      legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)


    print ('save')
    builder.save()
    print ('Successfully exported model to %s' % FLAGS.output_dir)
```

I get the exported model and run it on Docker. The service loads ok but my labels are missing (the response comes with the originals labels from inception (imagenet)).
So I replaced the variable class_descriptions and put my own labels (class_descriptions = ['unused background', 'noeyeglasses', 'eyeglasses']).

The service loads the new version, the labels are there, but the all the responses are wrong.

I need some help. What is necessary to retrain a model with my own labels and export it to use in tensorflow serving? (I already saw all links and tutorials, but all of then tells about serving the original incepetion (without retrain) or about the mnist).
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but here are some notes from a colleague on TF-serving: "I read the full question and the export code and don't find anything obvious. If I had to guess, there is something either mis-configured (aka corrupt) with the variables (weights) or tensors. Both of those would be issues with the model."

Comment: I am dealing with the same thing. Did you manage to solve it?